# Extracting data from txt using URL in Python

Tags: python, text-extraction

I have a URL which contains txt [data](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt)
From this URL I want to extract a particular section of data:

data here:
[image: Data]

I have added the screenshot of the txt file. In the screenshot you can see "Table of Contents". From these table of contents I want to extract the textual data of a particular Item number for example I want to extract data from a Part 2 Item 5 which have data on page number 12.
Can anyone help me in extracting this particular data using python

Comment: Reposted from deleted comment by Shivendra95: *This is the [link to the data](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt). From this link I'm trying to extract a particular section of data. In the screenshot provided you can see there are several items in the Table of Contents. From these items I only want to extract data of a particular item for example Item 7. MANAGEMENT'S DISCUSSION AND ANALYSIS which is present on page 14. I'm unable to extract data from that particular page as this only a txt document, I'm not able to parse it properly to get the desired result*

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could go about this. The first, and probably the most simplistic, would be the [`string.find()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm) method. Of course, that assumes that you know what you are looking for, you just want to use a program to fetch it instead of manually.

However, after looking at the way the document is formatted, there's the possibility that you could pass it to something like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), although I really wouldn't recommend feeding that type of document into BS4, you'd likely get a large number of errors.

The third option is possibly the easiest method (as far as I can tell) which would be to construct a regex to search the document for a string matching what you want.

In your given example of Part 2, Item 5, you could write a simple program that would look like the following:

```
import re
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt")

str_to_check = r.text

what_i_want = re.findall(r"(?i)(Part 2,? Item 5)", str_to_check)

print(what_i_want)
```

A site like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) could be very helpful in learning how to construct the regex you would need.

Comment: I'll surely look into this. Thanks!!. Now I can try something. I was stuck and didn't know where to start.

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can split your text into pages, and print the content of the page that you want:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt")

r_text = r.text

text_pages = r_text.split("<PAGE>")

# get content of page 12
page = 12
text_page_12 = text_pages[page+1]
print(text_page_12)
```

Comment: Is there a way to find the page number of a particular ITEM number. I have several documents like the one I have provided link for and the page number differs for different items. If I could find a way to find the page number of a particular item number, it could be very useful for me

Answer (score 0):

Get Table data with Requests and BeautifulSoup then you can do other operations like save it to txt file or anything else.

```py
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64618978/extracting-data-from-txt-using-url-in-python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_data(url):
    r =  requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.content


url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt"
data = get_data(url)

soup =  BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

table = soup.find("table")
print(table)
```